# QSqlQuery how to get value of a count?

Tags: c++, qt, qsqlquery

I have a query that is just getting the count of table based on some criteria eg:

```
QSqlQuery query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM some_table WHERE some_value = :something");
query.bindValue(":something", "something");
```

my question is how do i get result of this back, obviously this is where you would use

```
query.value(int);
query.value(QString);
```

But the docs say that int index one shouldnt be used because we dont know what the index would be andi cant use the string one because there is no filed to define as the one i want the result for. so assuming i am correct in saying that how is it that i can get the count integer value into a int variable from this query

cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make an alias to field count. Like this:

```
QSqlQuery query("SELECT COUNT(*) CNT FROM some_table WHERE some_value = :something");
```

and then query by name `CNT`

Comment: When doing that i get `QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record`

Comment: Did you call `query.exec()` and `query.first()`

Comment: executed the query yea, but didnt put first, will try it now

Comment: Thank you :), having read that `first()` will position itself on the first valid record that makes perfect sense cheers

Comment: will probably change that variable name though dont want to typo that!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use: **Query.next(); Query.value(0).toInt();**

For this msg: QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record
you should do: **Query.next();** to change the pointer to first record!