# How to get total number of rows/records in an sqlite table

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

i want to know how to get the total number of rows/records in an sqlite table and assign it to a variable. I did this;

```
    QSqlQuery query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM class1_bills");
```

But the problem is, how do i assign the result to a variable? 
I tried;

```
int rows = query.seek(0);
```

and;

```
int rows = query.value(0).toInt();
```

Yes, I know doing that accesses just the record at field position  **0** in the table. But it seems Qt's query methods are for accessing particular records at field positions only. If i'm wrong please correct me. So how do i get the total row count in the table?

Comment: possible duplicate of [QSqlQuery how to get value of a count?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26039000/qsqlquery-how-to-get-value-of-a-count)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The query returns a single column and a single row.

Just read that value:

```cpp
query.first();
count = query.value(0).toInt();
```

Comment: If you pass a query to `QSqlQuery` constructor it will be executed, no need to call `exec()`

Answer (score -1):

It's simple, just like any other query:

```
int rows = 0;
QSqlQuery query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM class1_bills");
if (query.next()) {
    rows = query.value(0).toInt();
}
// Do something with rows
```